# Unicode Character Encoding in Dompdf

Tags: character-encoding, tinymce, dompdf

I have a website where users can submit short texts (up to 5 lines) via TinyMCE into a database. Now, I want to output these texts as a PDF with dompdf. This worked surprisingly easy until I stumbled upon a text that includes a bear face made of unicode characters: ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ
In the final PDF everything except the "eyes" of the bear was questionmarks. I believe, this should be an easy task to fix but until now all my attempts failed, also because I didn't succeed in changing the font dompdf used.

**So, how do I display unicode characters correctly with dompdf?**

Let's get more into detail at what I'm doing here:
I use TinyMCE 3.5.10 with `entity_encoding` set to `numeric`. So, in the database, the bear face is stored like this: `&#661; &#8226;&#7461;&#8226;&#660;`

When parsing the inputs, I use dompdf 2.0.3 in a pretty much unmodified setup. My code looks like this:

```
// Include autoloader
    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    
    // Reference the Dompdf namespace
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    
    // Instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    
    while($entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allBadges)){
        $html .= '<div style="text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;">'.$entry ['text'].'</div>';
        $html .= '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>'; // only one text per page
    }
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
    
    // Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    
    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();
```

Before every text I set the font to "sans-serif" because that acts as my default font. The TinyMCE allows to select between two different fonts (Arial and Times New Roman) but since most users use Arial anyway and TinyMCE seems to only save the font if it was changed by the user, this was the most reliable setting. If a user changed the font to Times, dompdf uses "serif" as font-family, and I'm pretty much okay with this. But for the bear face (and probably other unicode characters) the output is this:
[image: Just questionmarks where a cute bear should be.]

Now, even though encoding seems to be my personal hell for the last year or so, I still am pretty stupid when it comes to actually fixing encoding errors. My first guess was to just use a different font. Since the dompdf wiki states that Helvetica is supported, I tried using it as my default font family but it didn't even show up in the final PDF. I probably have to enable it in dompdf or something, but at this point I'm just lost, even with the wiki. Then, I tried to use `DejaVu Sans`, since the wiki states that dompdf supports these fonts. It kinda worked, I guess? But also, it didn't and looked like this:
[image: The bear has ears, but still no nose.]

Also, with DejaVu the font size seems to be bigger, creating additional problems.

So, yeah, this seems like a really small problem, but it already took way too much time to not get fixed. Now, I hope, that maybe you can push me into the right direction, since I guess that there are even multiple solutions to this problem.

Comment: Check on the web, which font you used. The font you listed do not support all Unicode characters: there is a limit of glyphs per font. Usually we use many different font (hopefully on same family or design). Probably you should embed the font (also do not expect your users have the font you are requiring, and note: Windows now is changing default fonts)